# How can I bind list from database into checkbox in AngularJS?

Tags: c#, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I bind a list from a database into checkboxes in AngularJS?

This list contains ID and Names and I want to show only names. After a checkbox is checked I need to get the associated ID.

I get a list of features

```
var PlanFeaturelst = Helper.ConvertCustomEnumToList<EnFeature>();
```

This `Enum` (`EnFeature`) has a custom `Enum` attribute which has ( ID, Description and Display Text )

I send this list to angular in ViewBag :

```
$scope.initPlan = function (serverparam) {
    $scope.JAdminPlan.PlanFeatureValues = angular.copy(serverparam.featureTemp);
}
```

HTML :

```
<div ng-repeat="feture in JAdminPlan.PlanFeatureValues">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="feture.ID" ng-change="getID(feture.DisplayText)"/>
    &nbsp; 
    {{feture.DisplayText}} 
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know why people downvoted this question? you expects us to work as your "free of charge" employee by providing you an answer for your problem without you first explain what you have done, what is your exact problem, and no details whatsoever. Stackoverflow is not a place to get an answer to your homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to help you with assumption that it's not involving ASP.Net controls, just pure HTML controls with Angular

`persons` is an array of object: `{name: "Mark", id: "00001"}`. In this case any changes  to `persons` will affect the displayed text inside `<li>` tag and vice versa

HTML:

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="person in persons">
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="person.selected" ng-change="onChecked(person)"/> 
     span {{ person.name }}
   </li>
</ul>
```

Controller(javascript part):

```
$scope.onChecked = function(selectedPerson){
   console.log(selectedPerson.id)
}
```